# How to do animation of sequential data with d3.js?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a sequential data. Data is an array divided into 30 steps.
In the first step I draw initial data. Then I take data from second step, compare it with data from previous step. And make some animation/transition.

Now I want to repeat animation for the rest of 28 steps.
If I will use code like this

```
var old_data = start_data;
for (var i = 0, i < rest_data.length; i++){
    var new_data = rest_data[i];
    var diff_data = diff(old_data, new_data);

    var t0 = d3.transition().duration(3000);
    var selection = d3.selectAll('g').data(diff_data)
    selection.transition(t0).attr('my', function(d,i) { ... });
    old_data = new_data;
}
```

it will not work because transition() is async code.The loop run faster than complete the first animation. And at best I will have an animation between data[0] and data[29].

What is the best way to create an animation with sequential data like my?

Use `d3.transition().on('end', function() {...})`, where `function() { ... }` some function with closure where I will store `old_data`, `rest_data` and other variables?
I don't like this solution because I have many variables to calculate `diff_data`, and I have to keep them in the closure.

Comment: Are you suggesting that because it is async you can not start the next animation until the previous one is finished? I've created animations in d3 where several were happening simultaneously.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct: the `for` loop will run to the end almost instantly, and it will simply call that bunch of transitions at the same time, which, of course,
 will not work.

There are some different solutions here. Good news is that `transition().on("end"...` is just one of them, you don't need to use it if you don't want.

My favourite one is creating a function that you call repeatedly with `setTimeout` or, even better, with `d3.timeout`.

This is the logic of it:

```
var counter = 0;//this is, of course, a counter

function loop(){

    //if there is a data element for the next counter index, call 'loop' again:
    if(data[counter + 1]){ d3.timeout(loop, delay)}

    //access the data using the counter here,
    //and manipulate the selection

    //increase the counter
    counter++;

}
```

Have a look at this demo:

```js
var data = [30, 400, 170, 280, 460, 40, 250];
var svg = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", 500)
  .attr("height", 100);
var circle = svg.append("circle")
  .attr("cy", 50)
  .attr("cx", 250)
  .attr("r", 10)
  .attr("fill", "tan")
  .attr("stroke", "black");

var counter = 0;

loop();

function loop() {
  if (data[counter + 1]) {
    d3.timeout(loop, 1000)
  }
  circle.transition()
    .duration(500)
    .attr("cx", data[counter]);
  counter++
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: won't your solution become out of sync if some transitions are interrupted?

Comment: Yes, since the loop doesn't depend on the transitions​.