# Delay to the next data item, appending one by one, time after time

Tags: javascript, d3.js, delay

I need only to delay circles (apear one by one), but this `delay()` is ignored.

```
  D3_svg.selectAll().data(lst).enter().append("circle")
  .attr('cx', d => d.x).attr('cy', d => d.y)  // position
  .attr("r", 10).style("fill","red")          // layout
  .transition().delay(2000)                   // time to the next
```

There are many complex suggestions ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38534333/287948)), using timer, etc. **I need the simplest**.

Comment: Perhaps adapting `timeout()` of [this other problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45260420/287948).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it's possible to literally **append** the elements sequentially, with a delay, the necessary code would be too cumbersome for D3, and you'd end up bending over backwards: it seems to me that all you want is to the elements to **show up** in the screen sequentially, one by one. They can be appended at the same time.

That being the case, we'll use a simple `selection.transition`. However, we need to transition some attribute: one cannot transition *non-existence* to *existence*, it makes little sense.

The most simple way to make the element showing up in the screen is transitioning its opacity. For the delay, a function that takes the index (the second argument) of the elements is enough. For instance, one element every 1 second:

```
.delay(function (_,i){
    return i * 1000
});
```

Here is a basic demo:

```js
d3.select("svg").selectAll(null)
  .data(d3.range(50).map(() => [Math.random() * 300, Math.random() * 150]))
  .enter()
  .append("circle")
  .attr("r", 5)
  .style("fill", "teal")
  .style("stroke", "white")
  .attr("cx", d => d[0])
  .attr("cy", d => d[1])
  .style("opacity", 0)
  .transition()
  .duration(0)
  .delay(function(_, i) {
    return i * 200
  })
  .style("opacity", 1)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg></svg>
```